# Как можно вычислить позицию пиксела приближенного значения по оси ординат на линейной диаграмме?

Tags: javascript, математика

На этой диаграмме присутствуют значения на оси ординат от 0 до 1000 и мне известны их координаты относительно холста (canvas)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу получить координату пиксела относительно оси ординат, допустим, значения 235?

Comment: Линейное соотношение (пропорция), если вам известна пара значений и соответствующие координаты

Comment: @MBo, можете написать формулу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = y_min + (value - value_min) * (y_max - y_min) / (value_max - value_min)
```